# Call JPanel into another JPanel from a different class

Tags: java, insert, include

I'm trying to make a GUI application with Java.

I would like to call/include a JPanel-2 with some code into another JPanel-1 (as container) which is in a separate class (Mainclass).

Would this work?

```
Jpanel Japnel1 = new Jpanel.getcontentpane().add(Mainclass.panel-2);
```

Answer (score 1):

`JPanel` does not have a method to return a `Container` via 'getcontentpane()'.

A `JPanel` is in itself a `Container` (see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JPanel.html).

If you want to add a `JPanel` to another JPanel then as with any Container, use its `.add( Component comp)` method, as follows:

```
JPanel myJPanel1 = new JPanel();
JPanel myJPanel2 = new JPanel();

myJPanel1.add( myJPanel2 );
```

The question is too vague for further advice.

Comment: even if the second panel (myJPanel2) comes from another class?

Comment: even if the second panel (myJPanel2) comes from another class? what i am trying to do is, make a main Windows with buttons (for example 4 Buttons) on the left side,, and a JPanel in the centre of the window (lets call it MAINCONTAINER), wen a user clicks on a button then the appropriate Jpanel associated to that button is triggered and appears in the MAINCONTAINER,, when a user clicks on another button same thing, associated JPanel appears in the MAINCONTAINER,, i hope it's clear enough and thanks for the effort

Comment: even if the second panel (myJPanel2) comes from another class? what i am trying to do is, make a main Windows with buttons (for example 4 Buttons) on the left side,, and a JPanel in the centre of the window (lets call it MAINCONTAINER), wen a user clicks on a button then the appropriate Jpanel associated to that button is triggered and appears in the MAINCONTAINER,, when a user clicks on another button same thing, associated JPanel appears in the MAINCONTAINER,, i hope it's clear enough and thanks for the effort